# Favorites: load appropriate icon dynamically inside 'echo'?

Tags: php, mysql, nested, favorites

I'm trying to implement a favorites-system on a website like e.g. on stackoverflow.com: if you click the star-icon, the image is exchanged to show it's now a favorite. Just that in my case it's not questions but users who get favorited. So far no big problem.

However, I'd like PHP/MySQL to *remember* which users are favorites of the current visitor and decide dynamically which respective icon to use upon loading the page. *Without* that feature, my (somewhat simplified) code looks like this:

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT id, username FROM users";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

     //Insert nested query here (explanation and code see below)

    // Display each user:
    echo '<div class="favorit"><input class="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$row['id'].'"><img src="../img/ ' .$img_name. ' "  alt="" class="icons"/><br>Favorit</div>'; //generates error "Notice: Undefined variable: img_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\..."

    }
?>
```

This is my database:

[image]

How can I make the application remember the favorites of the current visitor and display the appropriate icon *$img_name*? My guess was to do a nested query inside the first one above but I couldn't get it to work:

Code of nested query (to insert into the code above):

```
//query the favorites of the current visitor:
$q2 = "select favorite_id from favorites where users_id=" . $_SESSION['reg_user_id'] . "";

   $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);

   //there may be more favorites, so loop through them:           
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ //generates error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\..."


       //if the respective user is a favorite:
       if($row2['favorite_id'] == $row['id']){                      

        $img_name = "favorite_full.svg";
       }                     
       else {
        $img_name = "favorite_contour.svg";
       }
   }
```

I get the following error messages (also see code comments above):

1. Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs...
2. Notice: Undefined variable: img_name in C:\xampp\htdocs...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
"SELECT u.id, u.username, f.favorite_id IS NOT NULL AS is_favorite
 FROM users AS u
 LEFT JOIN favorites AS f 
    ON u.id = f.favorite_id 
    AND f.users_id = {$_SESSION['reg_user_id']}"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same error messages: 1.Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs...
2.Notice: Undefined variable: img_name in C:\xampp\htdocs...

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, they do not mix. @bromelio You're using `mysqli_*` function to connect and query, then using `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, relying too much on code completion I missed the "i" in mysqli_fetch_array. That solved the first error message, great! For the second one I additionally had to move the declaration of one $img_name-instance out of the nested "while", now it works like a charm! @Fred -ii-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fred -ii-'s hint (to exchange mysql_fetch_array for mysqli_fetch_array) and moving the declaration of one $img_name-instance out of the nested "while" I was able to make the code work.

**New** code of nested query (to insert into the code above):

```
                    $img_name = "favorit_kont.svg";
                    $q2 = "select favorite_id from favorites where users_id=" . $_SESSION['reg_user_id'] . "";
                    $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);

                   //loop through favorites:           
                   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                       //if the respective user is a favorite:
                       if($row2['favorite_id'] == $row['id']){                      

                        $img_name = "favorit.svg";
                       }                     
                   }
```

Comment: If you use my query with the JOIN, you don't need nested loops. Everything comes in one loop.

Comment: Can I also filter for the records where "is_favorite" equals 1? @Barmar

Comment: Is this a question about my answer? You should post the comment there. Anyway, if you use an INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, you'll only get the rows where the user is a favorite.

Comment: Ok, next time. Yes, I know about INNER JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN. However, meanwhile my query has become more complex and it would be great if there was a possibility to do something like "WHERE is_favorite = 1"? Shall I post a question of ist own on that? Tks! @Barmar

Comment: You can use `HAVING is_favorite = 1` or `WHERE f.favorite_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: But either of those is equivalent to changing to inner join, since the only difference between inner and left join is whether the result includes null rows from the favorites table.

Comment: That works great, thanks! Yes, JOIN would be more elegant, but I'm now joining _three_ tables and Need the flexibility to Show all records of the third one, not just the favorites, so WHERE f.favorite_id IS NOT NULL is perfect for me! @Barmar

Comment: You won't see the records of the third table if the join matches a row  where `favorite_id` is null.